# Altium - Keepout Area Causing Short-Circuit Warning

Tags: altium, design-rules

I have the following footprint in my PCB library with 6 through hole pads:
[image: PCB Screenshot]

When I add the purple keep out area (to either the Keep-Out layer or the top layer), I get a bunch of short circuit warnings when I validate the footprint:

[Warning]   Component Validator Shorted Copper Connection Between Pad Free-6(150mil,25mil) on Multi-Layer And Pad Free-4(100mil,25mil) on Multi-Layer

I tried unchecking both vias and through-hole pads in the keepout fill properties, but the warnings still appear.  If I remove the keepout fill, the warnings go away.

I'm fairly new to Altium but I don't understand how a keep-out area could cause a short circuit.  Does anyone have any ideas of what might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Your pads are inside the keep-out area. You can modify the keepout to be [object-specific](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/object-specific-keepouts-ad) or you could just place a small track-like keepout horizontally between the pins (not touching them) which will keep you from routing tracks between the pins on your footprint.

The latter way is how I did it on a similar Tag-Connect footprint. Possibly older versions of Altium lacked the feature to make keepouts object-specific, I don't really recall why it was done that way.

Comment: If it's upset about the Pads, how come unchecking SMD Pad and TH pad in the keep-out options doesn't make the error go away?

Comment: The DRC uses clearance constraints so it will complain about the design you have. Not sure about the component validator.

Comment: Thank you for your response but for this question my concern is the component validator